# How to convert Javascript, CSS, and HTML content into a interactive-pdf or .h5p page

Tags: html, pdf

I have a webapp that let users place dots on sitemap and link them to images.
The web app uses Javascript, CSS, and HTML.

### phase1

While the user is subscribed he uses a rich set of functionalities to:

- add dots on the sitemap and link them to images
- edit the dots: move, delete, link momultiple images etc ..
- etc..

This is done via the website that hosts the webapp.

### phase2

When the user ends the subscription, he gets a .zip file with the information that he created (sitemap, images, links between the sitemap and the images, etc..).
The user can then connect to the website that hosts the webapp, without signing in and get a subset of the functionalities (e.g. he can only click on the dots and see the linked images, but he can no longer edit the dots or add images).

I want to change phase2.
Instead of interacting with the webapp on the website, I want to "freeze" the webapp into a interactive-pdf, or h5p page that can be played independently without the webapp.

There are multiple reasons that motivate to do this:

- the webapp is complex, so engaging with the webapp is prone to more errors.
  If the small subset functionality of the final data, which boils down to showing the image when clicking on the hyperlink, can be done via h5p browsing, then the risks for runtime errors are greatly reduced.
- the interactive-pdf or .h5p file can be browsed by variety of tools potentially even when being offline.
- the end product can be re-designed to appear more simple.

### My questions:

- is it possible to **programatically** convert the Javascript, CSS, and HTML content into a interactive-pdf or .h5p page?
  Every end-product will be different (e.g. by the number of dots, and their location in the sitemap) so having to manually create the .h5p page every time is not practical.
- are there mobile apps (e.g. on Apple Store, or Google Play) that can read .h5p content locally, e.g. when the device is offline?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

Oliver Tacke, thank you for replying.

Up to few days ago, looking for a solution to my problem, I did not hear about h5p at all.

When looking into h5p, I see that

- many comments rlated to h5p that is a bit old - from ~5/6 years ago.
- h5p is frequently talked in context of education (e.g. Moodle)
- when I filed the question I could not even find a tag for 'h5p'
- I could not find forums for h5p in mainstream channels like Discourse or Slack

So I want to know if I'm in the right direction at all.
Is h5p a new thing that just takes time to pick up, or is it something that started a while ago and dwindlled down,
or maybe I'm wrong and it is currently more active than I think (I'm aware of h5p.org and I do see activity there).

Basically, I want to create interactive content that can work

- ideally offline, or
- online but with a mainstream browser/tool/website (i.e. without needing my special website)

In the design industry, I know there are interactive catalogues.
But I don't know if the user can download them and somehow (e.g. with an epub reader) read them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about creating PDFs programmatically, so I can only offer a partial answer for the H5P related part. Given the broad scope of your question, this may be acceptable as a comment.

H5P content follows a specification that is documented at https://h5p.org/documentation/developers/h5p-specification.

You would basically have to implement an H5P content type library (file) from the files that you are given by the service. I assume that the JavaScript and CSS files are always the same, then those could be reused directly (but potentially not legally). You would also have to add some more JavaScript that takes parameters and generates the HTML output that you get from the service. You would then have to model `semantics.json` to suit the parameters, and then you essentially have an H5P content type. You don't have to use the then available form based editor (which probably wouldn't make sense), but you could create the `content.json` file programmatically and put it into the H5P content file archive. To create that file programmatically, you'd have to create a converter that identities the parameters in the HTML file generated by that service and transform them into the H5P semantics/content format. Not sure if it made more sense to rather create an editor widget for H5P, so you wouldn't have to depend on the other service at all.

There are currently no known mobile apps that allow you to load and run H5P content. They are on the [roadmap of the H5P core team](https://h5p.org/roadmap), but I wouldn't expect them to work on those any time soon. There's the moodle app for the moodle LMS that allows to use H5P content offline, but it needs to be fetched from a moodle instance. There's [Lumi](https://lumi.education) that allows to run H5P content locally on Windows, MacOS and Linux, but not on Android or iOS. However, Lumi also allows to create single standalone HTML files from H5P content containing all the content and logic ready to play, so that would allow offline use on Android and iOS.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I edited my question above, following your reply.
From your post I understand that you are versed with h5p. Will it be possible to connect with you on the side to get more detailed information about the h5p project?

Comment: H5P has been around since 2013 and is still a very active project - but unfortunately the vast number of users (who love to get everything for free) face only a few people who (openly) develop for H5P. That has manifold reasons ... Most core development is done by the H5P core team (= the company [Joubel](https://joubel.com)). There are quite a bunch of content types that are contributed by others (myself for instance), but the core team is still the gatekeeper. I am active on the H5P forum at h5p.org, so feel free to ask questions there if they are beyond the scope of stack overflow.